# Do I need getters and setters and extra entity constructors?

Tags: android, ormlite

I am trying to use ORMLite for database persistence in Android project. It looks all good from examples. Once I start to use it, I found I do not completely understand its requirement and behavior.

Let's say I have a class called Bone which I would like to persist.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "bones")
public class Bone{
// user defined
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING)
private String color;
@DatabaseField
private double length;
@DatabaseField
private int quantity;

// db assigned
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int id;
public Bone(){
}

// constructors
public Bone(String color, int quantity) {
    this(color, quantity, 0);
}
public Bone(String color, int quantity, int id) {
    this.color = color;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.id = id;
}

public Bone(Bone old, int id){
    this.color = old.color;
    this.length = old.length;
    this.quantity = old.quantity;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public double getLength() {
    return length;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

1. What are the requirements for the names of getters and setters of its fields? 
   Does their names make any difference? Can I use one without getter and setter?
2. Besides no arg constructor, any other constructor is needed?

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) What are the requirements for the names of getters and setters of its fields? Does their names make any difference? Can I use one without getter and setter?

There are no requirements for getters and setters.  By default [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) uses reflection to build the entity fields directly.

If you set the [`useGetSet = true` field of the @DatabaseField annotation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#useGetSet%28%29) then you do neet get/set methods.  See the javadocs for the format.

> 2) Besides no arg constructor, any other constructor is needed?

No.  You only need an accessible no-arg constructor for ORMLite to instantiate the object prior to the reflection work.

Comment: Is there a way to use getter/setter for foreign collections?

Comment: Can you ask that question and provide more details on the user list @deviant?  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-user

Comment: By default this is a public no-arg constructor to every entity @kml_ff.  The problem comes when you add _another_ constructor.  That's when you would need to specifically add a no-arg constructor so it's always a good idea to do so from the start and label it as necessary for the ORM.

Comment: Thanks. But my main problem about ormlite is this http://stackoverflow.com/q/22709958/459904 @Gray I wait your reply for the linked question..